# getting specific xlsx attachment from outlook and saving it on my windows computer

Tags: python, outlook, xlsx, win32com

I hope you are well.

I have been doing some python practice with web scraping and have come across the win32com library and have been really struggling to get the attachment from my outlook email ( it is just the one)! I have managed to view all of the emails by the following code. I was wondering if you could help me with getting the attachment file called lets say "data_bay1.xlsx" as i am stumped on the errors. I can so far get the data from the email but i cannot get the attachment xlsx file and the attachment part of the code when i try to run it gives me errors.  Please see what I have done so far and I hope any of you can help. I am using anaconda and windows. Thank you in advance! Kind regards, Lily

```
   import win32com.client
   
#connecting python to outlook

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
 
#connecting to our inbox

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
(inbox)

# here we are ensuring the indexes exist so we can grab data

outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
for i in range(50):
 try:
   box = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(i)
   name = box.Name
   print(i, name)
 except:
   pass

messages = inbox.items

messages = messages.GetFirst() earlier
# get the last email
#message = messages.GetLast()
(message)

#to loop through the email in the inbox 

while True:
 try:
   print(message.subject) # get the subject of the email
   # if you use messages.GetFirst() earlier
   message = messages.GetNext() 
   # if you use messages.GetPrevious() earlier 
   #message = messages.GetPrevious()
 except:
   # if you use messages.GetFirst() earlier
   message = messages.GetNext() 
   # if you use messages.GetPrevious() earlier 
   #message = messages.GetPrevious()



# get the attachment

 attachments = message.Attachments# return the first item in attachments
 attachment = attachments.Item(1)
 # the name of attachment file      
 attachment_name = str(attachment).lower()
 attachment.SaveASFile(path+ 'C:\Users\lily\OneDrive - Dataenv\Documents + attachment_data_bay1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
#to loop through the email in the inbox 

while True:
 try:
   print(message.subject) # get the subject of the email
   # if you use messages.GetFirst() earlier
   message = messages.GetNext() 
   # if you use messages.GetPrevious() earlier 
   #message = messages.GetPrevious()
 except:
   # if you use messages.GetFirst() earlier
   message = messages.GetNext() 
   # if you use messages.GetPrevious() earlier 
   #message = messages.GetPrevious()
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` to find items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

The best you can do is filter the list down to only the items with attachments. For that use `PR_HASATTACH` (`DASL` name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B`) MAPI property and then loop through the returned items and process their Attachments collection.